# How to delete items in BeginCollectionItem combined with Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm following [steven sandersons blogpost](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) on how to make a dynamic list of items on a webpage.

His example doesn't use entity framework however. So far I've been able to store the altered entities, to add newly created entities (I check for an id of 0) but I can't figure out how to delete any removed entities.

Since I only get back the new situation, how can I know what has been deleted?

One way would be to compare the database, and check the id's with what I have gotten back and then delete the ones which didn't came back, but that just sounds like a weird approach.
I also think that approach would fail when there is some kind of paginas going on where you only see a partial representation of the complete data.

Any thoughts on what the postback of the controller would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you can either use AJAX and trigger deletion when the user removes the item or you can use another javascript code which will store Ids of all deleted items to hidden field. When the user finishes the editing and post data back to server you will get those ids from the hidden field and delete those records.

Comment: I like the second approach. This will make the objects not really destroyed until the user has pressed 'ok' and is fine with it's edits. I'm going to try it